# How to merge several un-continuous version in svn

Tags: svn, merge

I need to merge 867,868,871,895,959 these version from CH004 TO CH004-joy

IN CH004-joy working directory I run below command:

```
svn merge -r 866:868 ../CH004
```

It works, merge version 867 and 868 successfully.

But `svn merge -r` only work on continuous version。 In my case, i need to run   several commands to reach my demand

```
svn merge -r 870:871 ../CH004
svn merge -r 894:895 ../CH004
```

Is there more convenient way  ? (i try `svn merge -r 866:868 870:871 ../CH004`, buy syntax is not correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to merge ranges, use the `-r` switch. For specific revisions, you can use the `-c` switch. The `-c` switch refers to a specific change. 
For your issue:

```
svn merge -c 867,868,871,895,959 /path/to/CH004 /path/to/CH004-joy
```

A lot of the similarity between `-r` and `-c` just has to deal with syntax more than functionality as they both can handle single revisions and ranges. The revision switch on the other hand does offer some additional switches that -c cannot handle, like dates for example.

[More info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.change) on the `-c` switch (and the rest of the switches).

Comment: It works, thank you for you help, you give me a light to know more about svn merge. Thank you.